# Converting SQL date with format statement 113

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to format my date variable to the following: `19 Sep 2013 07:00` using the following expression: `CONVERT(nvarchar(max), MyDate, 113)`, but with no success. The value returned is the following: `19 Sep 2013 07:00:00:000` It appends the seconds and milliseconds to the value after being converted.

Is there another format type that I need to use?

Comment: No, there is no such format type. You should truncate resulting string or construct it from several parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is something better, but this works at least:

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar(20), MyDate, 113), LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(20), MyDate, 113)) - 3)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/21027/0)</kbd>

So it simply removes the last three characters, the seconds from the time part.